# Cannot make a shortcut for a binding using the new preprocessing feature of Knockout 3.0

Tags: knockout.js

So I want to save some work writing complicated bindings in HTML by creating a few shortcuts like the following one using the latest [preprocessing feature](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-preprocessing.html) from Knockout 3.0:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.shortcut = {
    //init: function() {},
    //update: function() {},
    preprocess: function(value, name, addBinding) {
        console.log(name + ': ' + value);
        addBinding('click', 'function() { alert(' + name + '); }');
    }
};
ko.applyBindings();
```

And use it like this:

```
<button data-bind="shortcut: 'hey!'">Press me</button>
```

It doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/cQvn9/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample would just want to put quotes around `name`, otherwise it tries to alert on the variable `shortcut`, which does not exist when bound.

So, like:

```
addBinding('click', 'function() { alert("' + name + '"); }');
```

Comment: Probably he meant to use `value` instead of `name`.

Comment: Duh.. Thank you, I did mean value.